# How to prove that every vertex of an LP in standard form non-degenerate solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Does the fact that every vertex of an LP in Standard Form is nondegenerate imply that the optimum solution is unique?  How to prove this theorem? If not can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Degeneracy arises when the objective "plane" is parallel to a constraint "plane", so the premise is obvious in up to 3 dimensions. My, doubtless simplistic, view is that such a result is entendable to any number of dimensions. So yes, the theorem is true, but how to prove it beyond my justification will depend on your definition of "proof".